# High DPI and dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I’ve installed Ubuntu on top of a Windows10 install and successfully now have a dual boot system.  However the boot menu that allows me to select the OS to boot from is extremely tiny.  How can I fix this so I can actually see the menu items?

Comment: This https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/can-grub-font-size-be-customised might help. "the boot menu that allows me to select the OS to boot from" is grub2.

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit Bruni's comment is good one.. What is your Ubuntu Version? what is your screen resolution?